# How to set message expiry in WebSphere MQ (queue) by Java code ( not by JMS API - time to Live )

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Can sombody share WebSphere Code for setting up expiration of message in Queue.

I know that ther is a JMSAPI to do set the expiration of message.\

But this JMS-API is not applicable to WebSphere MQ API of Java Code.

I am using the following Code  to produce the messages.

MQMessage.write  & MQMessage.writeUTF

regards
karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the link for more information.  Here is the basic of an MQ/Java application:

```
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
pmo.options = CMQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;

MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
sendmsg.messageId    = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
sendmsg.correlationId= CMQC.MQCI_NONE;
sendmsg.format       = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING;
sendmsg.messageType  = CMQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
sendmsg.expiry       = timeToLive; // expiry is in tenths of a second
sendmsg.write(msg.getBytes());

outQ(sendmsg, pmo);
```

Answer (score 3):

The base class to `MQMessage` has an attribute `MQMD.expiry`, an `int` measured in tenth-of-seconds.

Source: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQMD.html%23expiry